# Reading HTML with php giving wrong information

Tags: domdocument

I am trying to get some data from http://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios-productivity/id6007?mt=8&letter=A&page=10#page using the below code.

```
$some_link = http://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios-productivity/id6007?mt=8&letter=A&page=10#page;
$content = file_get_contents($some_link);
echo $content;
```

But i am getting wrong page instead of the original

Can you please tell me what the problem is?

Thank you.

Comment: Try reading the PHP language reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/

Answer (score 2):

You missed quotes when initializing `$some_link`. This will work.

```
$some_link = 'http://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios-productivity/id6007?mt=8&letter=A&page=10#page';
$content = file_get_contents($some_link);
echo $content;
```

it will open webpage because `$some_link` contains HTML code.This opens the same page as 
http://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios-productivity/id6007?mt=8&letter=A&page=10#page

I have already tried and it works fine